# Cycling through multiple strings c#

Tags: c#, string, loops, for-loop, cycle

I have 10 strings, all named q1,q2,q3, etc.

My question is, on button click, how do I make them cycle and display within a button?

Current code:

```
private void nButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g <= 10; g++)
        {
            rBox.Text = q(g);
        }
    }
```

Clearly q(g) does not cycle appropriately, so I have come to you, Oracles of code, how would I accomplish this?

** Alternatively, if I wanted to remove the for loop, and instead would just want to increment g by one every time until 10, I assume the structure would resemble something like the following:

```
private void nButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g++
            rBox.Text = q(g);       
    }
```

However the question persists, how would I cycle through these strings?

EDIT: I've discovered these neat things called Lists, so I simply created a new list with

```
        List<string> questionNumber = new List<string>();
```

Then add the string

```
questionNumber.Add(q1);
```

As lastly display it through the text box with simple incrementation

```
private void nButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g++;

            rBox.Text = questionNumber[g];

    }
```

Comment: it should be q[g] not parentheses assuming you are using an array or list to hold your strings. if q is not a list it should be.

Comment: what is q?  Is it a list or a method?

Comment: Do you have separate variables named `q1`, `q2`, etc?  If you do there is no way to create a loop and loop through them.  You would have to use an array, a list, or any other enumerable set.

Comment: @entropic yes there is way using reflection but indeed not a good one.

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you want to concatenate the values into one large string or do you want to have the string on the button change over some interval

Comment: @Selman22 True, but like you said it's not a good idea, so why bring it up? :)

Comment: because it's not fair to say _there is no way_ while there is a way :)

Comment: @entropic q does not exist, however q1-q10 do as strings.

Comment: @RezaShirazian I apologize for the ambiguity, I would not like to combine any strings, but instead display each individual string as the g value is incremented.

Comment: @BbJug So if I'm understanding you correctly, you have ten different variables declared like so: `string q1 = ""; string q2 = ""; ... string q10 = ""`, correct?

Comment: @BbJug if you change the value each time in this loop this way you will not be able to see them as they will go too fast...

Comment: @eddie_cat Yes I realize that now, I've added a more logical approach with the simple g++ incrementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be putting them into an array and iterate over the array whenever you wanna operate on your strings.For example:

```
var values = new [] { q1, q2, q3, ... };

for (int g = 0; g < 10; g++)
{
   rBox.Text += values[g];
}
```

If your intention was to display one string at a time, on each click you can do so by creating a counter variable outside of the click event and increment it per click and just fecth the string at that index:

```
int index = 0;
private void nButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(index != values.Length) 
    {
       rBox.Text = values[index];
       index++;
    }    
}
```

You need to declare `values` a field or property of your class, and initialize it with your strings.In fact you can completely remove the variables and just use an array or list to store your values.

Comment: This won't work any better even if it addresses whatever `q(g)` means. The cycle needs to be maintained outside the button click, or handled differently for animations.

Comment: This will give values from q1 to qn concatenated. Was that what he was asking for?

Comment: this is just an example, that can be easily achieved by making the array a field or property

Comment: @RezaShirazian well overwriting the value on each iteration doesn't make sense so I took a shoot. maybe he wants to display one string at a time but I'm not sure.

Comment: This lead me to use Lists I've edited my question to include a working solution, thanks!